# SSL Principal Mapping in Kafka

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka

I’m working through a kafka implementation. I’m having issues with the ssl.principal.mapping.rules configuration.

I’ve successfully started up Kafka with the SSL encrypt/authenticate in place and I’ve successfully set up the super user using the full principal name. The issue arises when I flip on the ssl.principal.mapping rules. As soon as I implement this I can no longer access my topics as a super-user. When I disable the ssl.principal.mapping.rules and go back to the full principal name I still cannot access my topics. Below is my config and error I’m seeing. This was working fine until I added the ssl.principal.mapping.rules=RULE:^CN=(.*?)$/$1/U,DEFAULT section. Yes, the cert cn is ‘CN=TESTINSTANCE’

Error message below looks like a zookeeper issue possibly?

```
#CONFIG
broker.id=1

# SOCKET SERVER SETTINGS
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

# TLS
listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://kaf1:9092,EXTERNAL://kaf1pub:9093
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:SSL,EXTERNAL:SSL
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.keystore.location=/directory/to/key.jks
ssl.keystore.password=
ssl.key.password=
ssl.truststore.location=/directory/to/trust.jks
ssl.truststore.password=

# LOG BASICS
log.dirs=/directory/to/log
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

# INTERNAL TOPIC SETTINGS
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
auto.create.topics.enable=false
delete.topic.enable=true

# LOG RETENTION POLICY
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

# TLS KAFKA to ZOOKEEPER
zookeeper.connect=testzoo:2182/chroot
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
zookeeper.ssl.client.enable=true
zookeeper.clientCnxnSocket=org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.location=/directory/to/key.jks
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.password=
zookeeper.ssl.truststore.location=/directory/to/trust.jks
zookeeper.ssl.truststore.password= 

# GROUP COORDINATOR SETTINGS
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

# ACL SETTINGS
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
# For name mapping on principal
super.users=User:TESTINSTANCE
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false
ssl.principal.mapping.rules=RULE:^CN=(.*?)$/$1/U,DEFAULT
```

Error Msg:

```
Error while executing topic command : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1589471487877) timed out at 1589471487878 after 1 attempt(s)
[2020-05-14 15:51:27,882] ERROR java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1589471487877) timed out at 1589471487878 after 1 attempt(s)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService.getTopics(TopicCommand.scala:333)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService.listTopics(TopicCommand.scala:252)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:66)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1589471487877) timed out at 1589471487878 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
(kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like, broker is not available when you are trying to access the topic.
Please check the status of broker.